# Помогите найти позицию в строке

Tags: php

Есть лог который нужно проанализировать

```
$url = "http://capitalcity.combats.com/logs.pl?log=1392592040.6665&p=1";
$data = gzinflate(substr(file_get_contents($url),10));
```

через функцию **str_pos** пытаюсь найти позицию слова "Часы показывали",в итоге ничего не находит,пробовал регуляркой тоже 0 совпадение! Подскажите  в чем дело? в кодировке?

Answer (score 2):

Строка не находится из-за несоответствия кодировок. Сайт в кодировке windows-1251, а файл скрипта у вас в кодировке UTF-8. Если кодировка файла cp1251, то строка находится.

Если вы планируете получать данные из страницы, парсить ее вручную - не самая хорошая идея.
Воспользуйтесь инструментами для работы с HTML DOM

Comment: Я в парсинге еще не очень и силен,так как недавно начал им заниматься,подскажите чем ручной парсинг хуже? В основном пользовался регулярками,вроде никаких проблем не было!

Comment: 1. Регулярки сложнее поддерживать: при изменениях сайта приходится разбираться, что там понаписано. А в некоторых случаях эти регулярки получаются довольно сложными. Согласитесь, читать селекты в jQuery- или XPath-формате приятнее.

2. Зачастую регулярные выражения ресурсоемки (особенно, если там много .*)

3. При использовании регулярок приходится весь документ сразу грузить в память. А вот SAX позволяет работать с документами, загружая их части по мере необходимости.

Comment: Хотя это, конечно, - отдельная тема для обсуждений и в любом случае выбор стоит делать, опираясь на стоящую задачу. Минусы есть и там, и там.